# Shrink/Grow layout w/ animation on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a `DialogFragment` I'm trying to animate so that when `onClick()`'ed a confirmation appears underneath.
I have tried using `setVisibility()` with an Animator, but that isn't what I'm looking for. I want the layout to Slide In with the animation not appear after, or conversely disappear before.

I have been playing with some code from Github here https://github.com/ThePreviousOne/Example
 `

```
    handle.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            float startHeight;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            startHeight = slideDownView.getHeight();

            // Adjust the slide down height immediately with touch movements.
                if (down) {
                LayoutParams params = slideDownView.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (int) (startHeight - 300);
                slideDownView.setLayoutParams(params);
                down = false;
            } else {
                LayoutParams params = slideDownView.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = (int) (startHeight + 300);
                slideDownView.setLayoutParams(params);
                down = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

This works but I dont know how to connect the new code to an animator so I can control the speed the fragment resizes at

Comment: Do you have a mock (video, gif, etc) of the animation you're shooting for?

Comment: https://github.com/ThePreviousOne/Example/blob/master/untitled.webm
play at 0.1x speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom animator that updates the height property at each frame of the animation. For example:

```
int startHeight = slideDownView.getHeight();
// Note that you should not hardcode "300" as that will be different pixel values on
// different devices - get the value from a dimen resource or scale by the
// device density
int endHeight = startHeight - getDistanceToAnimate();

// Create a simple int animator that animates between the starting and ending height
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startHeight, endHeight);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        // On each frame, update the view height
        int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = value;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
       // Once the animation finishes, you might have to update the view's final
       // height and / or its `layout_height` attribute.
    }
});

animator.setDuration(getAnimationTime());
animator.start();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this code make the animation really choppy,I tried tweaking this and looking again for other methods, but no luck. Any further help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am using this extensively throughout my app for "expand" and "collapse" animations and it works just fine. Perhaps there is something else with your app / setup that leads to it "choppy". Sorry, but hard to say without more info.